# GPIO stop working nodejs Raspberry Pi, Gpio no longer enable

Tags: gpio, pi-2, node.js

2 months ago, I configured my raspberry to use GPIO. I don't remember exactly what I did, but I do remember needing to configure something to enable GPIO.
It worked great.

2 months later and multiple reboots, the code fails on the first 2 line.
I'm at a loss to figure out why this is failing. I am suspecting the GPIO are no longer enabled.

I could use some pointer being that I'm a newbie.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
var valuefd = fs.openSync('/sys/class/gpio/gpio5/value', 'r'),
```

I run this code with sudo node xxxx and the following error is produced

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'sys/class/gpio/gpio5/value'
```

When I do a *sudo ls /sys/class/gpio*, I get the following:

```
export gpiochip0 unexport
```

I don't see gpio5

When i do a *sudo ls /sys/class/gpio/gpio5*, I get the following:

```
ls: cannot access /sys/class/gpio/gpio5: No such file or directory
```

Any help or suggestions where to poke next would be appreciated.

I'm running the OS that came with the raspberry pi. I believe this is Debian.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not using pi-gpio, I did experiment with pi-gpio. It would appear a side effect of using *pi-gpio.open* is to create an entry
in */sys/class/gpio/gpio5*

I ran *sudo node*

```
require('pi-gpio').open(29, 'input', function(err){console.log(err)})
```

then magically the entry appeared in */sys/class/gpio/gpio5* and my program started working.

Comment: Because pins manipulated via sysfs must be exported before they can be used: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt I.e., you can accomplish the same thing by writing `5` (plus a newline) to `/sys/class/gpio/export`.

Comment: This question has been bumped to the homepage as its been inactive for a while without an answer being marked as correct. If what you outlined in your answer solved your problem, please mark it as correct.